# Can CRC32 be used as a "Rolling Hash" as with the Rabin–Karp string search algorithm?

Tags: hash, crc32, string-search

I have a hardware CRC32 peripheral on a MCU that I would like to use to speed up string search. Normally this is done with one of the rolling hash functions described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash#cite_note-3. I'm hoping this is possible using CRC32.

I found this answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/22356300/1615960 but realized that it would only work starting with the current CRC and working backwards, reversing the CRC one character at a time. What I need to do is trim the CRC using the nth most recent char. For example:

- Search "helloworld" for "owo".
- CRC32 of "hel" = X
- Remove "h" from X = CRC32 of "el" = Y
- Add "l" to Y = CRC32 of "ell" = Z
- And so on.... until matching CRC32 of "owo" is found.

My hunch is that this is not possible with CRC32, I'm hoping someone can prove me wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. However I don't see how to use a hardware CRC-32 to help with that. It would be faster to simply recompute the CRC on every triplet of bytes.